# Powershell script returns exception when using ADSI

Tags: exception, powershell, adsi

I get exceptions when executing a Power shell script (v1.0) on Windows Server 2008 (32 bit).

It uses ADSI for searching a virtual directory before its deletion.

I get the following exception:

```
Exception calling "Find" with "2" argument(s): "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80005008"
At line:1 char:29
+ $iisMgr.psbase.children.find <<<< ("MyVirtualDir", $iisMgr.psbase.SchemaClassName)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

This is the code:

```
$vDirPath = "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root"
$iisMgr = [adsi]$vDirPath
$iisMgr.psbase.children.find("MyVirtualDir", $iisMgr.psbase.SchemaClassName)
```

(edit): from several blogs I read that the IIS6 Management Compatibility role service must be enabled to get the ADSI provider installed, and I already have it enabled, still having this exception...

Comment: According to the [KB for 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232282) (IIS5) 0x80005008 is `E_ADS_BAD_PARAMETER`.

Comment: The last parameter returns "IIsWebVirtualDir" in Powershell editor... dunno why it gives a bad parameter

Answer (score 0):

Do you try with only one parameter ?

```
$iisMgr.psbase.children.find("MyVirtualDir")
```

I dont know there, but I've this kind of COM error when I invoke a method with the bad number of arguments.

JP

Comment: I use PowerShell ISE to test the call and when I call your code snippet I get an unhandled exception:  Problem Event Name: PowerShell
  NameOfExe: powershell_ise.exe
  FileVersionOfSystemManagementAutomation: 6.0.6002.18111
  InnermostExceptionType: System.AccessViolationException
  OutermostExceptionType: System.AccessViolationException
  DeepestPowerShellFrame: tem.Management.Automation.MethodInformation.Invoke
  DeepestFrame: nterop.UnsafeNativeMethods+IAdsContainer.GetObject
  ThreadName: Pipeli..ution Thread
  OS Version: 6.0.6002.2.2.0.274.38
  Locale ID: 1033

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas:

- Do you authenticate when doing ADSI interaction?
- I guess you are not making use of the Global Catalog as per your example of $vDirPath. In any case have a peek at [See How to Modify Attributes That Replicate to the Global Catalog](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248717)
- Try running your Powershell session with elevated user rights (Right-Click Run As Administrator)

Comment: - no authentication, - i am not using the Global Catalog (I only open the PowerShell ISE and calling the statements from above, - i have already disabled UAC so that is not needed and to be sure tested with a user that is already admin and still having that error.

Comment: Can you add an example of an authentication call on ADSI ?

Comment: Could not find a specific way to authenticate :( Docs only says that you should be part of Domain, Schema and Enterprise Admins, so I guess the context is on how you launch powershell. Another idea: How about using **AppCmd.exe** to delete the virtual dir?

Comment: I use a VM. The host of the VM is Win7 and on a domain, but the VM is not on the domain. Should that be the reason for errors ? Also I want not to change the existing .ps1 script; I want the script to run successfully in my VM...